Can etcd watcher read older events?
Can etcd 3.5 watcher read older events? If yes, how? I inserted a few thousand key/values in etcd 3.5 and brought the revision to 75,000. But when I start the watcher to watch from revision 1000, I don't get any events.
This is the code I have:
cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
                Endpoints:   []string{"http://localhost:2379"},
                DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        })

 watchChan := cli.Watch(context.Background(), "", clientv3.WithRev(1000))

watchResp := <-watchChan // Edit: this call is blocking

var count int
startTime := time.Now()

for watchResp := range watchChan {
                
                for range watchResp.Events {
                        count++

                        // Print the time taken for every 10 objects
                        if count%10 == 0 {
                                duration := time.Since(startTime)
                                fmt.Printf("Time taken to watch %d objects: %v\n", count, duration)
                                startTime = time.Now()
                        }
                }
        }



Did you try checking the watchResp for an error, or CompactRevision to know if the events are available?

Edited my question. The first for-loop is never entered.

The docs make it sound like you should get at least one watchResp with an error. If that's not the case, I would check the server logs to see how it responds to the watch comand.

I added an additional line of code. I see that the channel read is blocking.
